# Why does mypy complain about my dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to do an update of a dictionary with a dictionary comprehension. My code works fine, but mypy raises an error while parsing the types.

Here's the code:

```py
load_result = {"load_code": "something"}
load_result.update({
    quality_result.quality_code: [quality_result.quantity]
    for quality_result in random_quality_results()
})
```

In that code the `quality_result` objects have those two attributes `quality_code` and `quantity` which are a string and a float respectively.

Here the code for those quality result objects:

```py
class QualityResult(BaseSchema):
    """Asset quality score schema."""

    quality_code: str
    quantity: float = Field(
        ...,
        description="Value obtained [0,1]",
        ge=0,
        le=1,
    )
```

My code works as expected and returns the desired dictionary, but when running mypy it throws this error:

```
error: Value expression in dictionary comprehension has incompatible type "List[float]"; expected type "str"
```

I see mypy is getting the types correctly as I'm inserting a list of floats, the thing is I don't understand why it complains. I assume I must be missing something, but I'm not being able to figure it out.

Why does it say it must be a string? How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `load`?

Comment: Where did `load` come from? You have no type hint for `load_result`, so it appears that `load` is causing its type to be inferred as `dict[str, str]`, which would explain the error caused by the call to `update`.

Comment: Did you perhaps want to update `load_result["load_code"]` instead of `load_result` itself?

Comment: "Why does it say it must be a string?" Well, you're asking it to put values that are lists of floats, **into an existing** dictionary. Maybe it has some idea about what the value type should be for that dictionary, based on what it already contained?

Comment: is load type annotation is  `str` not `List[float]`  ?

Comment: Okay yes, `load` is a string. I'm updating the question. So you mean that mypy is inferring that the dictionary type must be `Dict[str, str]` and then fails because the update is not that type right?

Comment: `load: str | list[str]` this will work, if using python >=3.9

Comment: What type(s) **should be** valid for the values? (And if you don't care, then *why use mypy in the first place*?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line you write:

```py
load_result = {"load_code": load}
```

`load` is a string and this code makes mypy assume that the type for `load_result` is going to be `Dict[str, str]`. Then later on you write you dictionary comprehension where your values are of type `List[float]`.

Depending on what values you want in your dictionary, you can explicitly type it on the first line:

```py
load_result: Dict[str, Union[str, List[float]]] = {"load_code": load}
```

or

```py
load_result: Dict[str, Any] = {"load_code": load}
```

Comment: Exactly. I went with first option and the error wasn't raised.
Second should work too.